# How to get multiple items with JSOUP

Tags: java, android, jsoup

So I have a block of HTML I need to parse here:

```
<div class="item" style="width: 100%">
    <a href="example.com" class="sitelink"><img class="photo" src="placeholder_10.jpg" alt="Alt Text" title="title"></a>
    <div class="content">
        <h5><a href="example.com/moreinfo">title</a></h5>
        <p class="lifespan">More text 1<br> More text 2</p>
            <p>Some preview Text <a href="example.com/readmore" class="sitelink">Read More <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to pull lines 2,4,5, and link from line 6

But there are multiple sections like this on the page, which I also need to get.  I can't figure out how to iterate through each section and pull only the info that is in one div class then move on to the next.

I have tried a few things but they are so horribly wrong no sense in posting it here.  What I do have is here

```
Elements metaElems = doc.getElementsByClass("item");
for (Element metaElem : metaElems) {
    System.out.println(metaElem);
}
```

Which doing this I get all the div class="item" sections and only those.  But Im sure there is an easier way than parsing each line with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Elements items = doc.getElementsByAttributeValueMatching("class", "item")
for (Element item : items) {
    Element siteLink = item.getElementsByAttributeValueMatching("class", "sitelink")[0];
    //... and so on
}
```

More info here,
https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByAttributeValueMatching-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

If you like using css queries (like injQuery), try `doc.select`,

```
Elements items = doc.select("div.item")
for (Element item : items) {
    Element siteLink = item.select("a.sitelink")[0];
    //... and so on
}
```

https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-